# URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

### URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL.

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/getting-started,

```
curl -i -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/feed
  ?message=Hello World!
  &access_token={page-access-token}"
```

is the correct syntax for posting a page via the Graph API.

When I type this, I get the error message: `URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`.

I've double checked everything except the page token, but I have a long-lived page access token and a short-access page access token that I can generate at , and it is supposed to expire 2 months from now.

As far as the user access ID, I went to the debuggin page and got a message like this:

`Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out.`

I don't really know where to start trying to debug this stuff. If I go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/, I can select some options, but it always says `"invalid field user_access_id=myid& invalid field id=page_id"`, etc.

Comment: The line breaks and padding are only inserted for display purposes, you need to remove those and write the complete URL as one continuous string ...

Comment: @CBroe yes, I tried that. But StackExachange has poor word wrapping and poor codeblock expansion which looks like garbage, and the meta community is probably the worst community on the internet (as evidenced by their 1/1,000,0000 ratio of posts compared to other sites on their network) so I left the forced linebreaks. Appreciate your help, though.